# Adding markers to a map without a bitmap causes an Exception

Tags: android, google-maps

Adding markers to a map without a bitmap causes an Exception but I am having trouble catching the exception.

Sure fixing the problem is easy, just add the appropriate bitmap but it would be great to catch the exception without the app crashing.

```
private void showLocations() {

    for(Map location : locations) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = makeMarkerOptions(location);

        if(googleMap != null && markerOptions != null) {
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            markers.put(marker, location);
        }
    }
}
```

The Exception occurs as addmarker()

```
11-03 10:26:29.297 13148-13148/au.com.gaiaresources.microblitzbeta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: au.com.zzzzzzz.zzzzzzzz, PID: 13148
    com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11744448:9)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.n.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11744448:7)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cz.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11744448:25)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ba.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11744448:487)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.k.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11744448:94)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:507)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addMarker(Unknown Source)
```

How do I catch this exception? I tried catching com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b but it does not exist?

```
private void showLocations() {

    for(Map location : locations) {
        try {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = makeMarkerOptions(location);

            if(googleMap != null && markerOptions != null) {
                Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                markers.put(marker, location);
            }
        } catch(com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b ex) {
            getDependencyService().getLogger().error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
        //Your code
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        getDependencyService().getLogger().error(t.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't catch(Exception ex) be better?  I want to catch the actual exception not everything.

Comment: Yes, it is better. But even better to avoid exception at all.